# How to place a dot after every number in notepad++?

Tags: text, notepad++, editor

I want a dot after every number in notepad++.
So `1 abc` should be `1. abc`

But there is a `ALT0160` (hard space) already after every number.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this regex, here the steps:

From Notepad++

1. press the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to enter the find and replace
   mode
2. Select the Regular Expression option
3. In the "Find what" field place this: `(\d+)`
4. in the "Replace with" field enter `\1.`
5. Click <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

So from a file like this:

`1 abf
2 gbl
26 loksdgs`

you will obtain:

`1. abf
2. gbl
26. loksdgs`

Tested with Notepad++ v7.5.9.
Hope this help you.